# restful API redirect for a web app, changing base urls

Tags: html, rest, clone, reverse-proxy

I would like to deploy a web app developed and maintained by another person, but supply a few different API backends (restful, I think).  It is an ember.js based app.

An obvious solution is to fork web code, search and replace required base urls. A disadvantage I would need pull and merge the updates, and not sure is it easy with git.

Comment: Maybe you can convince the original maintainer to provide a base url as an option?

Comment: Merging in git is usually pretty painless. The more you can apply the open-closed principle in your changes, the more likely it will be entirely painless.